# working between local repository branches in git

Tags: git

I had an SVN background before and I get used to working between branches alternatively as a charm with it.

however, when I was trying to get myself familiar with GIT, I only found this VC work differently in the above-mentioned aspect.

for example.

in GIT. I initially created a branch called "Master".

```
master
======
car.rb
```

Then, I branched out into a new branch "new_branch".

```
new_branch
==========
car.rb
airplane.rb
```

from this point, I continued working on my recently added class "airplane.rb" so on and so forth. and then added it to the index.

and finally I needed to switch back to work on the master branch again.
what I only found when I did so was in the branch "master", the newly added file from "new_branch" was still there. so, I got no idea how to work with at that moment.

what do you normally do when it comes to switching between branches very often like my case?

any advice would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Did you add and commit airplane.rb? I feel that it is untracked, so git won't delete it when switching branches

Comment: what I did was just stage the file via "git add ." command. CharlesB, do you mean, in git, it requires me to commit working files before switching back to another branch? Could you shed some light on me for the correct way of doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You put `airplane.rb` in your staging area, which means it's not committed yet. When switching branches, git will keep your staging area intact, so that's why you still see it when going back to master.

You need to commit your changes when you are ready to do so, as the staging area is just... staging! It allows you to prepare the commit, but if you don't commit the changes aren't controlled.

Comment: yes, I think I'm just confused. It's logical to have changed files committed before switching branches. Thanks, anyway!

Comment: You can commit those working files, or you can also use git stash. Stash is a temporary holding area for in process files.